# Parse CLI won't upload non-js files

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to send iOS push notifications using my Cloud Code (I can't use Parse's Push APIs as my app is built using ionic and all their docs expect native).

I have it working as a standalone script locally using nodejs, but when I go to upload it to parse, I get:

```
Uploading source files
Note that the following files will not be uploaded:
parse_cloud_code/cloud/cloud/cert.pem
parse_cloud_code/cloud/cloud/key.pem
Uploading recent changes to scripts...
The following files will be uploaded:
parse_cloud_code/cloud/cloud/cloud.js
parse_cloud_code/cloud/cloud/cloud_test.js
parse_cloud_code/cloud/cloud/credentials.js
parse_cloud_code/cloud/cloud/fs.js
parse_cloud_code/cloud/cloud/push-notification.js
parse_cloud_code/cloud/cloud/push-notifications_test.js
parse_cloud_code/cloud/cloud/tls.js
Finished uploading files
Error: Failed to load cloud/cert.pem with: Could not find file cloud/cert.pem
    at Object.exports.readFile (cloud/fs.js:24:17)
    at readFile (cloud/push-notification.js:45:8)
    at body (cloud/push-notification.js:56:5)
    at cloud/push-notification.js:147:3
    at cloud/push-notification.js:156:3
    at cloud/cloud.js:5073:5
    at cloud/cloud.js:5082:3
    at main.js:1:13
```

How can I get the `.pem` files into the cloud code? I tried renaming them to `.js` but then Parse wanted them to actually be syntactically JS files. Imagine that.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this situation, as I had a similar problem. Any non-js file that I must upload I would rename to .ejs. So the parse CLI will upload it and them you can use it inside your cloud code.